# What happens when running a LCD at lower clock speed

Tags: arduino, lcd, clock

I need to display a still image (just the same grey color all over, so no need for difficult calculations what to display where) using only an Arduino Duemilanove (ATMega 328) and a Sharp LCD panel ([datasheet](http://www.gaw.ru/pdf/Sharp/LQ150X1LGN2.pdf))<sup>*</sup>.

However the datasheet assumes a clock speed between 50 MHz and 80MHz, way to much for a simple Arduino. What will happen if I try to use the monitor at a much lower clock rate? Remember, I try just to display a uniform, non changing color. Will the display begin to flicker? Also, what might happen, if I fade the color?

<sup>* It is part of a project to demonstrate what's possible using an Arduino and old electronics. So I restricted myself not to use any other *complex* bought electronic (your definition here). A small IC may be in order, a completely new board not.</sup>

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but just thinking; do you have to supply the clock from the microcontroller? It may be possible to use an oscillator with an enable input?

Comment: I only briefly looked at the datasheet, but clocking issues aside, it looks like it uses LVDS. I don't think you gonna be able to drive that with an AVR. You'll need either a special driver IC or an FPGA.

Comment: Datasheet mentions using this THC63LVDM83R LVDS transmitter IC, http://www.thine.com.cn/products_e/LVDS/F83R_F84B/pdf/DS_LVDSM83M63R_1.10.pdf

Comment: A brief glance at the data sheet suggests that the device generates an internal clock which is 4x the supplied clock, and uses that to receive data.  Only for clocks within the specified range should one expect any predictable association between input clock speed edges and data sampling points.

Answer (score 4):

The legally correct answer is "anything can happen": you operate a component outside its specs, so you are not allowed to count on any specific behaviour.

My best guess is that the display will flicker, or maybe (if you are unlucky) will not operate at all.